# Android, ImageView, unwanted padding

Tags: java, android

I'm using something like that to present my logo or user profile picture:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_bg"
    android:src="@drawable/account_circle_grey"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

`@drawable/circle_bg`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/colorWhiteOpacity"/>
    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp"/>
</shape>
```

and `@drawable/account_circle_grey` is just an image I took from [MaterialUI](https://www.materialui.co/icon/account-circle)(the black 192x192) and used [Final-Android-Resizer](https://github.com/asystat/Final-Android-Resizer).

The problem is that I get something like that:

[image]

Basically the problem is that when the user clicks and pick a picture, I use glide to load the picture to replace the default `@drawable/account_circle_gray` but as you can see the padding is gone:

[image]

The picture takes the full space, as it should!, what I wanted to add is `padding="5dp"` and that will give a bit of padding between the background and the `Glide` loaded user picture, **the problem** is that there is already a **weird** padding to `@drawable/account_circle_grey`, I noticed however that not all drawables get the padding, when I chosen an old picture I used as a full page background I didn't get the padding, maybe I can force android to pick bigger picture, why do I get this padding?

**Edit:**
To clerify I used [this](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide) tutorial to try all possible(scaleType+adjustViewBounds) values but nothing worked.

Comment: are you using .asBitmap()?

Comment: @elmontoya7 Is that Glide related?

Comment: Yes, use Glide.with(context).load(url).asBitmap().into(view); Sometimes the image wasn't shown properly using https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview and that fixed it.

Comment: @elmontoya7 so instead of using `src` to put the default I should load it via Glide using `asBitmap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the answers, the problem was so obvious but I made it complicated, although I used many "account_circle" images, what I didn't think was that they all comes with a transparent padding, so if the image is `192x192` for instance it's actual size is about `182x182` with `5px` transparent padding on each side, anyway the simple solution is to open it on photoshop, go to Image>Trim and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

set the `scaleType` of your `ImageView` to `centerFit` or you can add only high dpi drawable to your drawables

Comment: Added `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`, no change at all.

Comment: try `fitXY` too @AvielFedida

Comment: I used that guild https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide to try each value and nothing changes.

Comment: so thats because of you image source @AvielFedida

Comment: How can I force android to use only bigger drawable types(xxx-hdpi for instance)?

Comment: I do that by adding just the xxx-hdpi drawable @AvielFedida

Comment: I've tried something like that but I can't fine the right combination, can you edit your answer to reflect that...

Comment: I try: `android:src="@drawable-xxxhdpi/account_circle_grey"` but android studio alerts unknown resource type `@drawable-xxxhdpi`, can you edit with and example, it will really help.

Comment: you need to delete other drawables with other dpi's and only add the drawable with highest dpi @AvielFedida

Comment: I have tried, the only picture left is 1024x1024 and same behavior

Comment: can you upload your drawable? @AvielFedida

Answer (score 1):

This is likely happening when you're using images that are physically smaller than the size of your ImageView. You can scale the image to fill the space or use a larger image. A mix of both is likely the best solution.

To achieve the former of the two, try this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_bg"
    android:src="@drawable/account_circle_grey"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:padding="5dp" />
```

Notice that I reduced the width and height by 2x the padding. That is because adding padding to a view increases the entire view's size by the size of the padding. In this particular case we're adding 5dp to the left, to the right, to the top, and to the left. This means we must subtract left and right from the width, and top and bottom from the height.

Comment: Not working, I'm almost sure the images I'm using are two small, but is there a way to force the usage of xxx-hdpi drawable(1024x1024) `@drawable/account_circle_grey`?

Comment: I just checked the source you posted. The actual image @drawable/account_circle_grey has padding in the image itself. Try editing the photo to get rid of the padding!